# Angular route with 2 parameters not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've got this routing file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './app/homepage/homepage.component';
import { SearchpageComponent } from './app/searchpage/searchpage.component';
import { EventPageComponent } from './app/eventpage/eventpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomepageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'event/:name/:id',
    component: EventPageComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Whenever I try to navigate to an URL like `http://localhost:4200/event/asa/123`, it won't load the `EventPageComponent` (blank page) and Chrome gives me the following error in console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (http://localhost:4200/event/asa/inline.bundle.js)`

It does that for every bundle.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your script reference in `index.html` is incorrect. It appears to be pointing at `inline.bundle.js` (relative to the current path) when it should be pointing at `/inline.bundle.js` (absolute). That's my best guess given your problem, I see nothing wrong with the Angular code (nor could anything in Angular produce this error).

If you're using something like webpack for bundling they no doubt have a solution for this.

Comment: You were right!
The issue was that the `index.html` file had the wrong base definition.
I changed it from `<base href="./">` to `<base href="/">`

Thank you so much.